# Ruby interpreter name

Tags: ruby, interpreter, argv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the ruby interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814077/how-do-i-find-the-ruby-interpreter)

How do I get the currently running Ruby 1.8 interpreter name in Ruby (e.g. `/usr/bin/ruby`), i.e. the `argv[0]` passed to the C `main()` function. I'm not interested in `$0`, because that's the name of the `.rb` script file. I'm also not interested in `Config::CONFIG`, because that was filled when Ruby was installed -- but I'm interested in where it is running `now`.

Let's suppose `/usr/bin/ruby` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/ruby1.8`. How do I get to know if my Ruby script has been started as `/usr/bin/ruby1.8 myscript.rb` or `/usr/bin/ruby myscript.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Linux-only solution:

```
p File.open("/proc/self/cmdline") { |f| f.read.sub(/\0.*/m, "") }
```

For Ruby 1.8, `ruby.c` defines `VALUE rb_argv0;` which contains this information, but that variable is not available in Ruby scripts.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I find the ruby interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814077/how-do-i-find-the-ruby-interpreter)

```
require 'rbconfig'
RUBY_INTERPRETER_PATH = File.join(Config::CONFIG["bindir"],
                              Config::CONFIG["RUBY_INSTALL_NAME"] +
                              Config::CONFIG["EXEEXT"])
```

If you want Ruby specific information check out the `RUBY_*` constants

```
>> RUBY_
RUBY_COPYRIGHT     RUBY_ENGINE        RUBY_PLATFORM      RUBY_REVISION
RUBY_DESCRIPTION   RUBY_PATCHLEVEL    RUBY_RELEASE_DATE  RUBY_VERSION
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but this is not a good answer to my question, because I am not interested in where the interpreter was copied when it was installed (that's what I can get from `CONFIG::Config`), but I'm interested in where the interpreter currently is (i.e. the `argv[0]` of the C `main` function). What I'm interested in is not in `Config::CONFIG`.

Answer (score 0):

@injekt's answer has the path to the interpreter.

Here's how to find the particulars about the configuration.

Ruby's configuration info is stored in rbconfig.rb during compilation so we can see the particulars of the installation. That information is pulled into Object when the interpreter starts so we can get at the values:

```
>> Object.constants.select{ |c| c[/^RUBY/] }
=> [:RUBY_VERSION, :RUBY_RELEASE_DATE, :RUBY_PLATFORM, :RUBY_PATCHLEVEL, :RUBY_REVISION, :RUBY_DESCRIPTION, :RUBY_COPYRIGHT, :RUBY_ENGINE]

>> RUBY_DESCRIPTION #=> "ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]"
```

Comment: Thank you for providing interesting information about Ruby, but what you wrote doesn't answer my question.

Comment: As I said, "@injekt's answer has the path to the interpreter." I am expanding on it showing other information that is useful.